# How can i setup session in JS , for inputs?

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, session-storage

I know it's a silly question of this type, but im new to JS and im learning coding step by step. I'm curious how would i set up sessions for input values in javascript if i have this type of coding?

```
 <input type="text" id="name" >
 <input type="text" id="lastname">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">
```

Again i want to apologize for this question , and thank you for the help that you can offer me about this .

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "set up sessions for input values"?

Comment: George i want to  be able to take the value of the input field and store it in a session if thats possible.  As an example i know that to set a session we use the following code . sessionStorage.setItem("name","somevalue"); . short i want to store the values of these input fields into sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Now this code had help me out.What i wanted to do is to store the values of the input fields into sessions and be able to display them into the browser likethis:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" ><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="set sessions"><br><br>
    <p id="para"></p>

<script>

var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick=function(){
    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
    var lastname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;

    sessionStorage.setItem("name",name);
    sessionStorage.setItem("lastname",lastname);

    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=sessionStorage.getItem("name")+" 
    "+sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
}



</script>


</body>
```